# How can one find out which aspect ratio does the phone's screen belong to: WQVGA, WVGA, VGA, HVGA,etc?

Tags: android, screen, aspect-ratio

I need to create several devices in Eclipse's android virtual device manager. There is a field "screen ratio" with two options: long and not long.  [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) says

"long: Long screens, such as WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA
notlong: Not long screens, such as QVGA, HVGA, and VGA"

So my question is how can I classify any given phone to one of the WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA, etc?

Comment: I don't get it either.  WQVGA = (240x400) and QVGA = (240x400).  First is long, second is notlong.  The same goes for AVDs from Sony's SDK: Xperia Z1 and Zperia Z Ultra have 1080x1920, bit first is notlong and second is long.

Comment: Hi @RickFalck You find solution for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a list with some screen sizes organised by **aspect ratio**: **long** or **notlong**.

This may help others to have, for example, different layouts accordingly to the aspect ratio of the device.

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+   
|  Size  |  Resolution  |     Name     |     Device      |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+   
|                 Aspect ratio: long                     |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 10.1"  |  1280 x 800  | WXGA         |        -        |
|  7.0"  |  1024 x 600  | WSVGA        |        -        |
|  5.4"  |   480 x 854  | FWVGA        |        -        |
|  5.1"  |   480 x 800  | WVGA         |        -        |
|  4.7"  |  1280 x 720  | WXGA         |  Galaxy Nexus   |
|  4.65" |   720 x 1280 | 720p         |        -        |
|  4.0"  |   480 x 800  | WVGA         |  Nexus S        |
|  3.7"  |   480 x 854  | FWVGA slider |        -        |
|  3.7"  |   480 x 800  | WVGA         |  Nexus One      |
|  3.4"  |   240 x 432  | WQVGA        |        -        |
|  3.3"  |   240 x 400  | WQVGA        |        -        |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+   
|                 Aspect ratio: notlong                  |
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+  
| 10.1"  |  2560 x 1600 |      -       |  Pixel 10       |  
|  9.9"  |  2560 x 1800 |      -       |  Pixel C        |  
|  8.9"  |  2048 x 1536 |      -       |  Nexus 9        |  
|  7.0"  |  1200 x 1920 |      -       |  Nexus 7        |  
|  7.0"  |   800 x 1280 |      -       |  Nexus 7 (2012) |  
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+   
|  6.0"  |  1440 x 2560 |      -       |  Nexus 6        |  
|  5.7"  |  1440 x 2560 |      -       |  Nexus 6P       |  
|  5.5"  |  1440 x 2560 |      -       |  Pixel XL       |  
|  5.2"  |  1080 x 1920 |      -       |  Nexus 5X       |  
|  5.0"  |  1080 x 1920 |      -       |  Pixel          |  
|  5.0"  |  1080 x 1920 |      -       |  Nexus 5        |  
|  4.7"  |   768 x 1280 |      -       |  Nexus 4        |  
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+  
|  3.2"  |   320 x 480  | HVGA slider  |        -        |
|  3.2"  |   320 x 480  | QVGA         |        -        |
|  2.7"  |   240 x 320  | QVGA slider  |        -        |
|  2.7"  |   240 x 320  | QVGA         |        -        |
+------- +------------- +--------------+-----------------+
```

**List of acronyms:**

```
+-------+------------------------------+
| WXGA  | Wide Extended Graphics Array |
| WSVGA | Wide Super VGA               |
| FWVGA | Full Wide VGA                |
| WVGA  | Wide VGA                     |
| WQVGA | Wide QVGA                    |
| HVGA  | Half-size VGA                |
| VGA   | Video Graphics Array         |
+-------+------------------------------+
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution